# Run PHP script in background on Apache start/restart(Windows Server)

Tags: php, windows, apache, windows-server-2008-r2

I've installed Apache 2.4 with PHP 5.4 on Windows Server 2008 following instructions from this manual: 
[Apache installing manual](http://lifeofageekadmin.com/how-install-apache-2-4-php-5-4-and-mysql-5-5-21-on-windows-7/).
Apache runs as a service now.

My application requires a php websocket script to run in the background. I'm running it manually with:

```
php myscript.php
```

The question is: Is there a way to start a background script automatically on system(apache) restart?

I found the following [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992938/is-it-possible-to-launch-a-php-script-at-apache-startup), but I didn't know where I could find an apache startup script for Windows.

Any help will be much appriciated.

Comment: what do you mean by running in the background? A cron? Auto prepended?

Comment: Well the script ment to run 24/7 and should be listening incoming requests. So at system reset it should auto start just like I would type in 'php myscript.php' in the console and leave the console open.

Comment: There is no reliable way to keep a php script running 24/7. How are the incoming request generated? What do they do?

Comment: The script is websocket server like this one: https://github.com/GulDmitry/php-websocket-server.

Comment: Just needed a way to refresh some browsers in case some event occurs on another. App is working localy on a few machines only and this is the solution I came up with. Might not be the best practice :P What would you suggest then?

Answer (score 13):

I come up with a solution :)

**Create** an environment variable pointing to your Apache directory

```
APACHE_HOME = C:/PATH/TO_APACHE
```

**Rename** `%APACHE_HOME%\bin\httpd.exe` to `%APACHE_HOME%\bin\httpdVendor.exe`

**Create** a batch file and put the following code :

```
php myscript.php
%APACHE_HOME%\bin\httpdVendor.exe -k runservice
exit 0
```

**Download/Install** the free software [BatToExeConverter](http://battoexeconverter.com/) (next, next, ...)

**Open** the  installed converter and **open** your freshly created batch file

**Click** on the button **Build EXE** (let the default configuration)

**Save** the file : `%APACHE_HOME%\bin\httpd.exe`

**Start** your Apache Server

Tested on : Windows 7, Apache 2.4, Advanced Bat to Exe Converter 2.92

Comment: A very creating solution :)

Comment: It's clever, but also a hack that has to be reimplemented any time the Apache binary is updated.

Answer (score 2):

Use built in Windows Task Scheduler which triggers `.bat` script, which calls curl with defined url.

1. Download curl from http://curl.haxx.se/download.html and extract curl.exe on any directory, but we will use `c:\backgroundtasks`
2. Adjust script below to your needs:

   cd c:\

   cd c:\backgroundtasks

   curl http://localhost/path/to/script.php

   exit
3. Configure Task Scheduler to run as basic task:

   - General tab - as system account (to run when you are not logged in server)
   - Triggers tab - adjust frequency
   - Settings tab - at bottom set `If the task is already running...` to `Stop the existing instance`

Answer (score 2):

The best method here would be to use Windows services dependencies.

Make a `php-websocket-server.cmd` file with any necessary environment settings (e.g. changing to a directory, setting PATH, etc...) with the last line:

```
php myscript.php
```

Install the [Windows Server Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17657), to get `srvany` and `instsrv` to create a [user defined service](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890/en-us). Note the install path as you'll need it in the next step.

Open a `cmd` shell and run:

```
<path_to_resource_kit>\instsrv PHPWebSocketServer <path_to_resource_kit>\srvany.exe
```

Next, create a file `php-websocket-server.reg` containing the following (update for your environment):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\PHPWebSocketServer\Parameters]
"Application"="c:\\path\\to\\php-websocket-server.cmd"
```

Import it by double-clicking or `regedit /s php-websocket-server.reg`

Back in your `cmd` shell:

```
sc config Apache2.4 depend= PHPWebSocketServer
```

to make the Apache2.4* service depend on your php service. Now, when Apache is started, the php service will be brought up first. And likewise, if you stop the php service Apache will stop along with it.

<sup>*the howto indicates that the service is named "Apache2.4" but you may want to verify in your installation.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

When running as service, you won't have the startup script.

Execute some service implementation that allows running other programs as services, and then make the new service (which is running your script) a dependency of the Apache service. However, this will not restart the script when apache restarts.

[One possible solution using SrvStart](http://www.howtogeek.com/50786/using-srvstart-to-run-any-application-as-a-windows-service/), and [another using ServiceEx](http://serviceex.com/).

Perhaps don't install Apache as a service, and then edit the startup/restart script, and use the above method to run Apache as service (instead of using Apache's own installer).

Answer (score 1):

Create bat file,e eg 'myphp.bat' containing `path/php myscript.php`. Include the correct path to php if it's not path'd.

create a bat file, eg runmyphp.bat containing

> AT 00:00 /every:M,T,W,Th,F "cmd /c /path/myphp.bat", again including the correct path.

Then use explorer to drag runmyphp into the startup folder, so it will always run on system startup.

Google 'windows at command' or 'windows cron' to get all the correct syntax for the 'at' command, but you can currently find a detailed explanation [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726974.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I found another answer C:\wamp\scripts\wampserver.lib.php this file is run every time when your wamp starts

include your file path `include_once("file_path");` to this file and its done . this is perfect solution which you want

Enjoy!!!!!!!!!

Comment: That only works because wamp uses it's own manager: `wampmanager.tpl`. If you use `WAMP`,  you could just as well alter the `wampmanager.ini` and alter the `[StartupAction]` section.

Comment: @HugoDelsing yes sir First I thought to use cron job but it is not perfect solution , I found this way and I don't think any other way is more easier then this

Answer (score 1):

Although the solution of Halayem Anis is very creative, I think its important to note that you can never be sure that a `PHP` script keeps running in the background. So if you choose to start your script on "Apache start", then you probably end op resetting Apache quite often, simple to reboot your script.

I assume that's even how you came to this question, as on a normal server you never have to touch the Apache reset button. It starts on system start and then it just runs. If that was the case, you could simple run your `php myscript.php` command on start up.

Considering there is no way to make sure the script keeps running, I would use a different approach, where I check if it is running and if not, restart it.

So the first step is to make it possible to track if the script is running. I would go for the simple approach where your `myscript.php` writes a single byte to a file every 5seconds or so. This way I can use the last modified time on the file to see if it is still running, because `last modified time +  5 seconds < now == not running`.

You could also store the last access time in a database every 5 seconds or so. Might be slightly faster then accessing files if you have a lot of traffic.

The second part is to have each request check if the script is running. For this two work I would use the `PHP.ini` to prepend a php script on every request. You can do it with the [auto_append_file](http://php.net/auto-append-file) option.

This prepend script would work like this:

```
<?php
$filename = 'checkonline.txt';
$cmd = "php myscript.php";
if (filemtime($filename)+5<time()) {

  //run in background without freezing php
  //based on code posted on PHP exec manual, linked below
  if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){
    pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r")); 
  }
  else {
    exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");  
  } 
}
?>
```

Make sure to check how [filemtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) and [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) work and what you need to keep in mind. They work slightly different on Windows/*nix.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap-up all your required processes in a batch file and use [RunAsService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415409/run-batch-file-as-a-windows-service) 
With some tweaking, you can ensure that your service starts before Apache.