# How can i run php file automatically in windows7

Tags: php

I am using PHP and MySQL running in windows7.
I need to run a php script at the scheduled time daily to send sms for birthday wishes.

Comment: windows has a task scheduler, use that

Comment: Does this thread help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035090/run-cron-job-on-php-script-on-localhost-in-windows

Comment: More info, what server are you using? Nginx, Apache, IIS, Vanish?

Comment: sir , i am using an apache server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your command in [Task Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7), and setup the DateTime Interval you need.

To Execute PHP Script, you need to mention php path and the file to be executed, for example:

```
D:/xampp/php/php.exe D:/xampp/htdocs/execute.php
```

Comment: And I answered with my flexible solution this some long time ago. It is easy to customizable, add multiple  urls, add multiple frequencies etc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718865/run-php-script-in-background-on-apache-start-restartwindows-server/28095198#28095198