# How to run a script whenever Apache is started/restarted?

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I have a WAMP environment and would like to support WebSockets. For this purpose I bought a module and installed it. However, I would like to be able to run a standalone script once WAMP is started. However, after a long search I did not find out how can I do this with WAMP.

I have, among others read this: [Is it possible to launch a php script at apache startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992938/is-it-possible-to-launch-a-php-script-at-apache-startup)

However, I do not have an etc folder and I am confused about what should be done and where. The suggested example is:

```
restart)
        [..]
        php -q /tmp/myscript.php &
        ;;
```

which is nice, I want it to be executed as a background script, but:

- I do not know where should this be included
- I would like to execute the script on start as well
- I wonder whether the syntax is the same for WAMP
- I hope that this will not run in the background even if Apache is stopped

Comment: @Machavity, thank you for pointing that post out. I have read that one as well and my question is slightly different. I specified in my question that I intend to do this with WAMP, while the other question is less specific and therefore allows solutions outside of WAMP. I am not against closing this question if it considered to be a duplicate, but would like to know an answer without environment variables, batch files, windows startup events or third-party tools. Is this possible solely with Apache?

Comment: AFAIK the Apache within WAMP is basically the same as a vanilla Apache install (just tied to the central config setup system). Did you try their solutions? They look very viable.

Comment: @Machavity, the best thing I found is the link in the question, but I do not know where that script should be added. I can see now that a part of my question is not visible. I will edit my question to make the invisible part visible, my bad.

Comment: @Machavity, sorry, I see it was visible but not well-formed.

Comment: @Machavity, I am still trying, but with no luck.

Comment: not, the syntax is NOT the same. you're on Windows, and that example is for Unix/Linux. the concept remains the same: they're just inserting a command to run a new script into the script that starts apache. you'd have to find whatever wamp uses to start apache and insert your command there.

Comment: @MarcB, that is what I am trying for hours, but I lack the necessary WAMP knowledge to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked the same question at [WAMP's forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,143486,143489#msg-143489) and the answer was:

> Hi,
>
> > Is it possible to launch a php script at apache startup?
>
> No.  Not with Wampserver.

The answerer was a [moderator](http://forum.wampserver.com/profile.php?2,19), therefore I have to believe that, unfortunately the answer is: no, that's not possible.