# Launch php script at apache2 startup

Tags: php, apache, debian, apache2, boot

I am trying to run a php script to restore a state after the server crashed, got restarted or smth.
Because the php script needs the database to run I first tried running it by creating a file in init.d, which did not work, it just started whenever it wantend.
So right now I think it is the easiest way to run the script on apache2 startup like discribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992938/is-it-possible-to-launch-a-php-script-at-apache-startup).
So currently I have added `php -q /var/www/scripts/testing.php & ;;` to `do_start()` in `/etc/init.d/apache2` like this:

```
do_start()
{
        # Return
        #   0 if daemon has been started
        #   1 if daemon was already running
        #   2 if daemon could not be started

        if pidofproc -p $PIDFILE "$DAEMON" > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
                return 1
        fi

        if apache_conftest ; then
                $APACHE2CTL start
                php -q /var/www/scripts/testing.php &
                ;;
                apache_wait_start $?
                return $?
        else
                APACHE2_INIT_MESSAGE="The apache2$DIR_SUFFIX configtest failed."
                return 2
        fi
}
```

But because this didn't work at all, I have also added this php execution to the `restart)` part as mentioned in the link. This looks like this:

```
 restart)
        log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC" "$NAME"
        do_stop stop
        case "$?" in
                0|1)
                        do_start
                        case "$?" in
                                0)
                                        log_end_msg 0
                                        ;;
                                1|*)
                                        log_end_msg 1 # Old process is still or failed to running
                                        print_error_msg
                                        exit 1
                                        ;;
                        esac
                        ;;
                *)
                        # Failed to stop
                        log_end_msg 1
                        print_error_msg
                        exit 1
                        ;;
        php -q /var/www/scripts/testing.php &
        ;;
        esac
        ;;
```

But still the script is not run. The php script looks like this:

```
<?php
file_put_contents('/var/www/html/log', "301,$timestamp,Recreating all connections after restart,N/A\n",FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

Because i wanted it to be as simple as possible, but the log file is still empty. I am open to any idea solving my problem.

p.s.: I have already tried to do this by a service in `/etc/systemd/system/` but since I am starting a connection that is supposed to be persistent, I have to use either `screen`, `nohup` or `disown`. I have tried those three, but no of this worked, they just didn't start the script. (was bash back then, I switched to php to be able to run it from the apache2 file)

Comment: Syntax is for the php script or a calling script that executes the php? Doubt a closing round bracket is valid php syntax after a command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use apache to start your script, but follow your first idea of using an own init-script unless your php script depends on the existence of apache.

Just place a shell script `callmyphp` into /etc/init.d that calls the php interpreter and passes your php script as an argument like:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/php -q /path/to/myphp.php
```

Don't forget to make your calling script executabel with `chmod 755 /etc/init.d/callmyphp`.

Then add your calling script via symbolic links to the desired run levels, i.e. by running `update-rc.d callmyphp defaults`

See also https://debian-administration.org/article/28/Making_scripts_run_at_boot_time_with_Debian