# How to make PHP variable "stick" across multiple invocations of script?

Tags: php, caching

In PHP, is there any way to make a variable "stick" across multiple invocations of my script? Specifically, I need to compute `hash_hmac('sha-256', $data, $key)` where ***data*** will probably be different on each invocation of my script, but ***key*** needs to remain the same for *all* invocations on a specific server (Apache2) instance. Actually what I need is that ***key*** is initialized to a pseudo-random value **once** per server (Apache2) instance. Please note that I do **not** want the ***key*** to be hard-coded or loaded from a config file. The ***key*** should be generated pseudo-randomly when the server (Apache2) instance is starting up, or when it is needed (read) for the first time. Also the ***key*** should "stick" in the memory for as long as the specific server instance running, but, as soon as the server instance is shutting down, it should be discarded with no way to re-construct it!

I would be fine if `$_SERVER` contained any value that is "unique" per server instance, with very high probability, so that I could just take *that* seed and pump it through a KDF in order to derive my unique key. But it seems there is **no** such entry in `$_SERVER`, or am I missing something?

Also, I can **not** use `uniqid()`, because it will give a *different* unique value on each call (script invocation), **not** a value that is unique per server (Apache2) instance.

Furthermore, I can **not** use Cookies or `session_start()`, because ***key*** is **not** supposed to be *per-user*, and it **must not** be visible to the users! I understand that contents of `$_SESSION` are *not* visible to the user(s), but I do **not** want to track any data ***per user*** when that is **not** *necessary* – and when it would only serve as a workaround for the inability to retain a single "global" value.

I could probably use an "in-memory" DB with something like SQLite, but this really feels like taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut. This "problem" of requiring a variable (value) to be initialized once and then "stick" across multiple invocations of a script seems like something that would arise naturally in **many** applications! So is there no simple straight-forward solution for this?

---

#### EDIT

For clarification: In this particular setup, there is **no** security risk in using the same MAC key for all users (of a particular server instance), because we never show that key to the user(s). We want to ensure that the user returns the "authentic" message to the same server instance where it was originally obtained from. If a user modifies its given message, we detect this on return, because the MAC doesn't match anymore. The same holds true, if the message was returned to the "wrong" server, because different servers *shall* have different MAC keys and so the MAC won't match. Using a separate key ***per user*** doesn't improve things in this scenario and just is **not** *necessary*, but it would add new complication (i.e. session management) that I really want to avoid...

Comment: Put it in a file/database/cookie

Comment: Would shmop work? First read attempt would need to initialize the key. https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php

Comment: To your last paragraph, yes, the problem is very common, and we’ve got databases, file systems, memory stores, “secret vaults’’, etc. to support it. What is not common, however, is the “unique for the process’s lifecycle” aspect.

Comment: @ChrisHaas *"Would shmop work?"* It would survive an Apache restart. Only a restart of the whole machine would reset it. And there could be a race condition if the first two requests are executed at the same time.

Comment: You could use the technique given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992938/is-it-possible-to-launch-a-php-script-at-apache-startup) to run a PHP script on Apache startup. That script would initialize a shared memory with shmop.

Comment: Using a "shared memory" (shmop) technically might work to persist data across multiple script invocations. But it feels like we are abusing the "shared memory", which is intended for ***sharing*** data between processes, as an "in-process" buffer - something that normally should be achievable with a simple `malloc()`'ed buffer, if we weren't limited by the tools that PHP gives us. Also, the `shmop_*` API is pretty cumbersome, for something as simple as making a variable "stick". Finally, how do I implement and properly synchronize a ***"one time"*** initialization with the `shmop_*` API ???

Comment: Why is the key not supposed to be per user / per session? that makes no sense.

Comment: *"which is intended for sharing data between processes"* Which is necessary when using PHP as CGI.

Comment: @Kaii I think, in theory, we might be able to use a separate key per user, but this is not *necessary*. What we actually want is a unique key per server. I'd only be willing to track a separate key *per user* if there is a requirement for that - **not** as a workaround for the inability to track a *single* key per server instance. Also, if we want to track a separate key per user, we'd have to use session cookies, right? This has legal implications, because we need consent from the user before we are allowed to store cookies (at least here in the EU). So that's something I'd like to avoid...

Comment: @Oliver I think "traditional" CGI passes parameters via command-line and environment variables, and the "output" is then returned via pipe (stdout). Modern *FastCGI* uses a network protocol (Unix Domain Sockets) to communicate between the "main" process and the "worker" prcocess. Neither of this uses "shared memory" in the sense of POSIX shared memory objects (i.e. the `shmop_*` API).

Comment: @Schraubstock1990 My thinking is totally opposite: I would always use a unique key per user or request, or whatever is the smallest possible share of encryption key. Only if there is a good requirement to use a shared key between requests / users i would do so. Best practices are here for a reason... see my other comments below my answer, I've read and answered there first.

Comment: @Schraubstock1990 everything you mention about PHP sessions is wrong: neither is the content of the session variables available to the user (unless your code sends it to him), nor is it necessary to use cookies. You only need to transport the session ID: you can submit the ID with GET or POST variables, so sessions also work for users _without_ cookies. A cookie is only necessary to re-identify the user when he closes his browser window and comes back later.

Comment: @Kaii I did *not* mean to say that data in `$_SESSION` is visible to the user. Okay, I see now that we can have PHP sessions without the need for cookies. But still I'm *not* willing to track any data separately *per user* (e.g. in a PHP session), as long as this is *not even necessary*. I think that using a *per-user* session just to carry over a value from one script invocation to the next – a value that is *not* actually user-specific and therefore could (should) be a "durable" global variable – would be a subpar  solution. I'd rather go with a *APCu-based* solution.

Comment: Late to the party, but is there any drawback of just using an environment variable for the *UNIX user running PHP and initialize it on server startup? It'll survive Apache being stopped, but if initialized on startup it will just be overriden.

Comment: @JohannesH. Yeah, using an environment variable may actually be a way. But the drawback that I see is that it is *not* a "PHP only" solution, but instead it relies on the initialization to be done "outside" of PHP before the PHP application starts.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since a satisfying solution was **not** readily available, I spent the afternoon creating a simple PHP extension that does exactly what I need. Since it may be helpful for others, I'm posting it here.

It generates a unique ID, via [`getentropy()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getentropy.3.html) system call, in the ***module initialization*** function, converts it to Base64 string and exposes it to the PHP user script as a constant via `REGISTER_STRING_CONSTANT()`. That is a straight-forward and efficient way to ensure that the ID is generated ***exactly once*** per server instance, when the server is starting up. It is then kept in "static" memory. Accessing the ID as a PHP constant also is *much* simpler than other approaches

It can be used like this:

```php
<?php
echo 'Unique instance ID: "' . PHP_INSTANCE_UNIQID . '"' . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

```php
<?php
$unique_key = hash_hkdf('sha256', PHP_INSTANCE_UNIQID_BINARY, 16, 'my-context');
?>
```

**See also:**
https://php-uniqueid.bitbucket.io/

I'm still a bit surprised that something like this doesn't exist in PHP already...

Comment: Note that it will only work with mod-php. In case of CGI, a new key will be generated for every CGI process.

Comment: @Olivier Is "classic" CGI still a thing? I would think its all FastCGI nowadays, where you have a single long-running process that communications with the "main" server process. So that should work fine too.

Comment: FastCGI uses a **pool** of worker processes. In your case, it means that every worker would have its own key.

Comment: @Olivier I think that is configuration thing? Anyway, I think I can live with that. After all, if we had several ***separate*** worker processes, then the APCu-based approach or any similar solution would face the same "problem", right? And, in my actual project, I don't use (Fast)CGI anyway.

Comment: Correct, in an FCGI setup, APCu memory is also *not* shared across instances.

Comment: FWIW, the `PHP_INSTANCE_UNIQID` is now shared across multiple processes (per user) 

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHPs built-in APCu cache to store the random value persistently within each running server instance until restart:

```
$instancekey = apcu_fetch('instancekey');
if (!$instancekey) {
    $instancekey = uniqid(); // or use whatever RNG you like
    apcu_store('instancekey', $instancekey, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be the most promising (simple) solution, thus far, that does **not** required an additional PHP extension. However there are two problems that come to my mind: The initialization is **not** "atomic", i.e. we could end up with two invocations of the script ending up with *different* keys (in the eraly phase). Also, to the best of my understanding, APCu does **not** guarantee that the entry remains in the cache for as long as the server is running, even if we did *not* set an explicit TTL. Entries that haven't been accessed recently may "soft" expire and be evicted...

Comment: **Update:** I think using `apcu_entry()` could be used to ensure "atomic" initialization. But the problem of expiring cache entries still remains. From the APCu docs: *"An entry is **soft** expired if no per-entry TTL is set [...] and the access time of the entry is older than the global TTL. Soft expired entries are accessible by lookup operation, **but may be removed from the cache at any time.**"*

Comment: @Schraubstock1990 well, at least I've tried. To be honest, I strongly suggest you don't do what you asked for and store the HMAC key _in the user _$_SESSION_ instead. Session variables are *not* readable by the user, they are stored locally on the server: only session id is provided to the user, not content. The session still exists after a service restart and could even be stored in a way that it the value exists after reboot. This way, a user will not notice your server restart between to requests. With your own solution, the second requests fails when you reset the server in between.

Comment: @Schraubstock1990 Why is key not supposed to be per user? Why share the same HMAC key between users for a long period of time? (until restart) I see a huge security issue here. Don't do that. Use a unique key _per session_ instead of _per server_. I see no reason not to.

Comment: There is **no** security risk in using the same MAC key for *all* users, because we ***never*** show that key to the user(s). We want to ensure that the user returns the "authentic" message to the *same* server instance where he got it from. If a user modifies its given message, we detect this on return, because the MAC doesn't match anymore. Same if the message was returned to the "wrong" server, because different server has other MAC key and so the MAC won't match. Using a separate key *per user* doesn't improve improve things here, but adds new troubles (session management).

Answer (score 0):

I am curious to know why you want to do this? What is the use case? You are asking for an approach that makes your application extremely tightly coupled to a specific setup on a specific web server on a specific platform or at least OS. for example, you can use your root Apache2 process ID:

```
netstat -lntp | grep apache | awk -F '[/ ]*' '{print $7}'
```

To get a unique process ID that will be changed with each apache2 restart, but as mentioned, this is a thing that will make you stuck to a specific setup, the previous command will be invoked using exec. For example, the previous command will not work when you run your PHP & Apache2 behind docker, using a function like `posix_getppid()` may fix this issue, but the function is getting the parent ID, so it is not a thing for Apache2.

On the other hand, relying on a random number/string as keys will make you lose the saved encrypted / hashed data.

Alternatively, you can go with something like saving the key in a tmp file, Database, or Session and use cronjob or scheduled task to reload your key periodically.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I need a "key" that is unique with very high probability, such as a pseudo-random string of bytes generated by a CSRNG. Something like a process-ID or host IP-address is **not** sufficient. Generating a random "key" is easy, e.g. with `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`, but making it persistent across multiple script invocation (for the lifetime of a server instance) is the problem! Had to come up with my own solution, as using an "in-memory" database or even a local file would be an unpleasant solution.

Comment: I'm **not** using the "unique" key for long-term encryption/storage, don't worry!. I just need the key to compute a MAC over a piece of information that I will provide to the client. When the client later returns the information to the server, I need to verify that the information actually originated from this specific server instance. So the key really must be unique per server instance. But we don't need to do this verification over more than a few minutes or so, i.e. there is **no** need to persist the key in the long-term.