# Can I persist a flag across all sessions?

Tags: php, session, php-7

I have an expensive operation that runs in my PHP application when the `/api/replicate` endpoint is requested. The operation takes roughly 30 seconds, so I want to prevent this endpoint from being called again until the operation is complete.

Normally, I would store a flag in the session data that indicates whether the operation is running or not and check this flag before running the operation. However, session data is specific to an individual user/browser. I would want this flag to persist across all sessions and processes (I am using Apache HTTP Server) so that another user cannot run the operation if it is already running.

I considered using a lock file and also considered persisting this flag to a database. However, I think the best solution would involve storing the flag in memory somewhere so that it does not persist if Apache is restarted.

Is there a way to globally persist a flag like this?

Comment: Session variables aren't accessible between users, so lock files or database would be the best way to go about it

Comment: First, I generally agree, use the DB or FS for this. That said, someone else had a question along these same lines a little while back, and I think there was some good discussion and answers that, even if they aren't for you, are at least a good read: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78056179/231316

Comment: If you don't mind the additional software running on your host you can install a redis cache and implement a simple lock on that.

Comment: Nothing you do on the server will "prevent the endpoint from being called". The best you can do is have the endpoint return an error while it's locked, or go into a wait loop waiting for it to be unlocked.

Comment: @Barmar that is the objective.

Comment: The earlier comments are correct. There isn't really anything much better than a flag file or the DB. Checking for a file lock may be the cheapest way.